# Where i can edit the store label in admin magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to edit store info and want them on in one line only.In sales_order_grid.xml
http://prntscr.com/qlsnho

Comment: inline edit for store only in order grid right ???

Comment: RK Rathod rather than long website name and store name i just want to keep simple store name.